# Changing filter on Realm notification

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, realm

I wonder if it is possible to use the same notificationblock on a resultset but change the filter? For example: I have two queries, one with isDelivered = true and one where isDelivered = false. I would like to have one Resultset with different filters and then switch the resultset depending on if I want to see delivered or undelivered items. Is that possible or do I need to create two notificationblock for this?

Comment: Any updates on this? Just ran into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to retroactively change the predicate query used to create a Realm `Results` object. But it is possible to attach the same notification block to two separate `Results` instances in order to share the handling logic.

```
let notificationBlock: ((RealmCollectionChange) -> Void) = { changes in 
   // Perform common update logic in here
}

let deliveredObjects = realm.objects(MyObject.self).filter("isDelivered = true")
let delieveredNotificationToken = deliveredObjects.addNotificationBlock(notificationBlock)

let undeliveredObjects = realm.objects(MyObject.self).filter("isDelivered = false")
let undelieveredNotificationToken = undeliveredObjects.addNotificationBlock(notificationBlock)
```

Comment: It complains of this: ```Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> ()' to specified type '(RealmCollectionChange) -> Void'```

Comment: Hmm, apparently it needs all the generic types defined as well: `let notificationBlock: (RealmCollectionChange<Results<MyObject>>) -> Void = { changes in`